# Read XML file and using it for 2nd XML in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to grab the value of the key field in the operators.xml, then compare its value with the start/end range in roles.xml, then add a role element and assign an appropriate value.

key 107 falls in the range of 1- 499, which is among user start and end. So the ID is assigned to user role. The name of role, i.e., user, or manager, can be hard coded.

Here is an example to illustrate my problem. I think many people can use this question for reference to achieve similar functionality.

**roles.xml**

```
<OperatorRange>
    <Role>
        <node_id>1</node_id>
        <user_start>1</user_start>
        <user_end>499</user_end>
        <manager_start>500</manager_start>
        <manager_end>699</manager_end>
        <training_start>700</training_start>
        <training_end>799</training_end>
    </Role>
    <Role>
        <node_id>2</node_id>
        <user_start>0</user_start>
        <user_end>0</user_end>
        <manager_start>0</manager_start>
        <manager_end>0</manager_end>
        <training_start>0</training_start>
        <training_end>0</training_end>
    </Role>  
</OperatorRange>
```

**operators.xml**

```
<Operators>
    <Opeartor>
        <key>107</key>
        <name>John Smith</name>
    </Opeartor>
    <Opeartor>
        <key>607</key>
        <name>Brad Johnson</name>
    </Opeartor>  
</Operators>
```

**expected result**

```
<Operators>
    <Opeartor>
        <key>107</key>
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <role>user</role>
        </Opeartor>
    <Opeartor>
        <key>607</key>
        <name>Brad Johnson</name>
        <role>manager</role>
    </Opeartor>
</Operators>
```

Comment: Are these elements names `user_start`, `manager_start` and `training_start` known in advance and fixed? Or can there be arbitrary role names in the input XML?

Comment: What's the difference between the two Roles in the roles.xml document?

Comment: user_start, manager_start and training_start are known in advance and fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed your xml to be like this as your "roles.xml" had some errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperatorRange>
  <Role>
    <node_id>1</node_id>
    <user_start>1</user_start>
    <user_end>499</user_end>
    <manager_start>500</manager_start>
    <manager_end>699</manager_end>
    <training_start>700</training_start>
    <training_end>799</training_end>
  </Role>
  <Role>
    <node_id>2</node_id>
    <user_start>1</user_start>
    <user_start>499</user_start>
    <manager_start>500</manager_start>
    <manager_end>699</manager_end>
    <training_start>700</training_start>
    <training_end>799</training_end>
  </Role>
</OperatorRange>
```

You didn't provide any logic for "role" node for your output xml. Hence that is left to you. Try out this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:MyUtils="pda:MyUtils">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Operators>
      <xsl:variable name="operators" select="Operators//Opeartor"/>
      <xsl:variable name="roles" select="MyUtils:getSecondXMLData()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$operators">
        <xsl:variable name="curnode" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$roles/Role">
          <xsl:if test="$curnode=node_id and $operators[$curnode]/key &lt;=user_end and $operators[$curnode]/key &gt;=user_start">
            <Opeartor>
              <key>
                <xsl:value-of select="$operators[$curnode]/key"/>
              </key>
              <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$operators[$curnode]/name"/>
              </name>
              <role></role>
            </Opeartor>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Operators>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Saurav, I am sorry for the errors in "roles.xml". I fixed the original post in order to avoid misleading the readers. I actually only need the values from the first <Role> node in roles.xml. I modified the code following your solution and get it working. Thank you!